# Is covariance all about accepting values?

Tags: c#, generics, covariance, contravariance

Is covariance all about accepting values?

I am learning the C# through the **CLR via C#** book. And I come across the following excerpt:

> Since T is covariant, it is possible to have the following code compile and run successfully:

```
// This method accepts an IEnumerable of any reference type
Int32 Count(IEnumerable<Object> collection) { ... }

...
// The call below passes an IEnumerable<String> to Count
Int32 c = Count(new[] { "Grant" });
```

I am confused here. Because the covariance is about having the type which is one of the base types of the required type. And as such the covariance is used only in the context of the return types. While in the example above we have a `String` (which is derived from `Object`, so that is contravariant, but not covariant) which is used in the context of passing arguments (but not returning values).

So, should we use in the example above the contravariant instead of the covariant (meaning that there is an error in the book)?

**UPDATE**

After the comments I got another question. Are the following definitions correct?

> **Contravariant** Meaning that the generic type parameter can change from a class to a class
>   derived from it. In C#, you indicate contravariant generic type parameters with the in keyword.
>   Contravariant generic type parameters can appear only in input positions such as a method’s
>   argument.
>
> **Covariant** Meaning that the generic type argument can change from a class to one of its base
>   classes. In C#, you indicate covariant generic type parameters with the out keyword. Covariant

Comment: `Covariance` and `contravariance` enable implicit reference conversion for array types, delegate types, and generic type arguments. `Covariance` preserves assignment compatibility and contravariance reverses it... [see more here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/), that isn't an error in the book and is correct.

Comment: `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant on `T`, the book is accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Josh pointed out the book is correct.

You can check [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) if you want to confirm it from another source.

> `IEnumerable<Cat>` is a subtype of `IEnumerable<Animal>`. The subtyping is preserved because `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant on `T`.

The two keywords in C# for those concepts are `out` for covariant and `in` for contravariant. In the `IEnumerable<T>` case this translate to `IEnumerable<out T>`.

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE**

You would have to inverse your definitions as follows.

> **Covariant** Meaning that the generic type parameter can be a certain class and all the derived classes from it (`IEnumerable<Object>` can be a `IEnumerable<String>` since `String` is a subtype of `Object`). In C#, you indicate covariant generic type parameters with the out keyword.
>
> **Contravariant** Meaning that the generic type argument can change from a
> class to one of its base classes. In C#, you indicate contravariant
> generic type parameters with the in keyword.

Comment: Also `in` is only applied for arguments and `out` is for return type and these can only be applied on generic interfaces.

Comment: My issue with this answer is the phrase _can change from a class to a class derived from it_. What do you mean by _change_? You can't assign an `IEnumerable<Object>` to `IEnumerable<String>` but it looks like that's what you're saying. I'm guessing you mean an `IEnumerable<Object>` can actually be a `IEnumerable<String>`. As someone who was confused about co- and contravariance for a long time I think using _change_ here is confusing, don't you think?

Comment: @Joelius thanks for pointing that out, I recognize that I have been in the same situation and things can get confusing really fast. Is my answer easier to understand now ? :)